# Nextjs and Image component getting Contentful CMS image.. larger kb in production than development

Tags: next.js, vercel, contentful, contentful-management

React/Next app on Vercel:
Images are from Contentful CMS - all from master branch.

**In local development:**
(npm run dev)
image sizes are less than 3x the size as when in production.

**In production**
Images in production are much much bigger, over 3x the size as development. huh!?

Anyone have any ideas why?

```
      <Image alt="some alt text" quality={30} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" src={`${imageSource}?q=40`} priority />
```

here is an image: Top shows smaller "development" image, same call, same image. As you see, production is 3x the size.

Any ideas as to why?

[image]